# Find related posts and rank them by relevance

Tags: php, sql

I have a website with different articles. The database structure is like this:

ArticleId | ArticleLocation | ArticleCategory | ArticleTopic

The actual text strings for the columns are in another table so all the columns are populated with numbers (integers)

I want to find related posts, meaning if a user reads an article with ArticleLocation = 1, ArticleCategory= 3 and ArticleTopic = 2, then I want to find top 5 of articles sharing the most of the same column values.

Any ideas of how to do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: most of the same = totally same?

Comment: What CMS are you using? Selecting from DB where ArticleLocation = 1, ArticleCategory= 3 and ArticleTopic = 2 shouldn't be to difficult?

Comment: No not totally the same. Suppose you have a posts with 3 column values in common, one with 2 and one with 1. Then they should be sorted accordingly.

Comment: pseudo code: SELECT from DBName WHERE ArticleLocation = 1 OR ArticleCategory = 3 OR ArticleTopic = 2 ORDER BY [the posts with most "OR" statements fulfilled on top]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the table is named `ArticleTable`, try the following:

```
SELECT *, (
CASE ArticleLocation WHEN :loc THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
CASE ArticleTopic WHEN :topic THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
CASE ArticleCategory WHEN :cat THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Relevance
FROM ArticleTable 
ORDER BY Relevance DESC
LIMIT 5
```

with `:loc`, `:topic` and `:cat` set to the relevant values.